Descriptions in a description
I am trying to write a format like this

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\setlist[description]{
    style=nextline,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
    \item[char.\textbf{isdecimal}(a)] For each element, return True if there are only decimal characters in the element.
    
    Calls unicode.isdecimal element-wise.
    
    Decimal characters include digit characters, and all characters that can be used to form decimal-radix numbers, e.g. U+0660, ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT ZERO.
    \begin{description}
        \item[Parameters] 
        \begin{description}
            \item[a] Input array.
        \end{description}
        
        \item [Returns]
        \begin{description}
            \item[out] Array of booleans identical in shape to a. 
        \end{description}
    \end{description}
\end{description}

\end{document}

and this is what I get

I do not know how to deal with the parameters and the returns any suggestion?

never do \usepackage{enumitem}\usepackage{enumerate} the two packages both redefine enumerate so over-write each other. Just use enumitem

If you are looking for a and out to be on separate lines from Parameters and Returns, you can try putting a blank line between \item[Parameters] and \begin{description}. You probably also want typewriter font (\tttext{something}) for anything fixed-width (e.g. unicode.isdecimal)

You shouldn't nest description environments which use nextline as the behaviour is liable to change and 'not what one would expect' according to the docs (page 12).

If you limit nextline to level 1, you can force the others using \hskip 0pt before the new description and \hskip 0pt followed by a blank line between the `\item[] and the final content. That's clearly a crappy solution, so I think looking for a different option would be the way to go. Have you looked at CTAN? You can search for packages by topic, which is sometimes helpful.
